# Probability of $n$ heads if coin is flipped until 8 tails.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

Suppose a fair coin is flipped until 8 tails occur. Let X be the number of heads that appear. What is the probability mass function of X? I answered ${n- 1 \choose 7}*(0.5)^n$, since it is a negative binomial random variable but this got marked wrong. I don't see how to get to any other answer. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean $P(X=n)={n- 1 \choose 7}(0.5)^n$? If so, how do you interpret $P(X=0)={- 1 \choose 7}$? (The actual probability should be $2^{-8}$; do you see why?)

Comment: Long story short: $X$ is *not* the count of *tries* until 8 tails, rather it is the count of *heads* that appear before the eighth tail.  For $X=n$ you want some arrangement of $n$ heads and $7$ tails among the first $(n+7)$ tosses, then a tail on the next toss; when making $n+8$ tosses with unbiased choice. (Fair coin).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $T$ is the number of flips until (and including) the $8$th tail. Then $T$ is a negative binomial random variable, with
$$ \mathbb{P}(T=n)={n-1\choose 7}2^{-n} $$
for $n=8,9,10,\dots.$

Since $X=T-8$, it follows that
$$ \mathbb{P}(X=n)=\mathbb{P}(T=n+8)={n+7\choose 7}2^{-n-8}$$
for $n=0,1,2,\dots$.